# Who died in the Game of Thrones episode, "The Long Night"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm mainly talking here about any named characters we know that died in the episode. I was trying to pay attention to see who died but it was so damn dark that I probably missed who and when. Those that I can remember seeing are:

> Edd, Lyanna Mormont, Jorah (possibly), Rhaegal (possibly) and Melisandre.

I think there were others and I can't remember if some did die or not.

Who died in Season 8 Episode 3, "The Long Night"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- Lady Lyanna Mormont: Died while fighting a Giant wight

  [image: At least I tried]
- Lord Beric Dondarrion: Died while saving Arya and the Hound

  [image: Thanks god, there's still whine]
- Edd Tollett: Died while saving Samwell Tarly

  [image: Pretty dolorous]
- Theon Greyjoy: Died while saving Brandon Stark

  [image: Seems like I wasn't the prince that was promised...]
- Mellisandre of Ashai : Died after the fight

  [image: Died because?]
- Night King : Assassinated by Arya Stark while tryng to kill Bran

  [image: Stabby Stabby from the back]
- Viserion: Died(again) when the Night King died

  [image: big blue crow]
- Ser Jorah Mormont: severely injured while saving Daenerys Targaryen

  [image: Maybe a kiss? No?]
- Qhono: Died leading the Dothraki's charge (thanks to @KharoBangdo for this one)

  [image: did he always had blue eyes?]
- Everyone resurected by Night King: same as Viserion, every named character who died and was resurected by the Night King ar any other White Walkers died

We can also see who *didn't* die if we watch the trailer for episode 4. For example,

> Both Drogon and Rhaegal are alive, and so is ghost

Comment: The Inside the Episode pretty much confirms Jorah dies so removed my comments that he may not have done.

Comment: Also, 99.9% of the Dothraki, and 99.8% of the Unsullied.

Comment: Hard to say about the Dothraki. We saw some run back from the initial lights-out, but not many, and who knows which or how many of them survived the rest of the night.

Comment: @Geobits we see a dothraki resurected amongst important characters, with the same apparence as Qhono, and not sure how good it is a s a source but according to [this wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Qhono), he is dead

Comment: The Night King reanimates, he doesn't resurrect (they're not alive again afterwards), so it doesn't seem correct to include any of those (including Viserion) in the list of people who died in the episode.

Comment: Do we know about Ghost? He charges in to battle, but isn't seen afterwards.

Comment: I think there's Alys Karstark as well. She was seen in Godswood along with Theon before the dead arrived. I haven't seen her dead, but apparently Bran was the only survivor there.

Comment: What happened to `The Hound` anyways?

Comment: Remarkably few named characters actually died, all things considered.